# router-link replace with vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

With the router-link tag with vue-router, "Setting replace prop will call router.replace() instead of router.push() when clicked, so the navigation will not leave a history record", according to the docs. But this doesn't seem to be happening for me, so I think I must be misunderstanding something. I have a navigation menu in my SPA and the router-link in each menu item has a replace prop. Yet when I click on each menu item in turn, it clearly does add to the history, in that the back button takes me back to the previous item, and I can actually see in the Firefox history the list of URLs being added to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a demonstration of that behaviour, at least the HTMLtemplate, would be helpful in helping you.

Comment: Well, an example of one of the router-links is this: `<router-link :to="{ name: 'edit-sale', params: { action: 'add' }}" replace>New Sale</router-link>`. That uses this route: `{name: 'edit-sale', path: '/sale/:action(add|modify)/:id?', component: SaleManager}`. HOWEVER...I find now that the back button is behaving as expected, so maybe I had just run into some cacheing issue?

Comment: Spoke too soon! With Chrome, I can keep clicking the back button and move through my navigation history - '/product/list', '/sale/add', whatever, even though all these links have been given the 'replace' prop. I don't think it's a bug, more a misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `<router-link :to='{path:'/test'}' replace> Go <router-link>` in component "history",after clicking "Go", the url is "..../test",the "history" component's url is still in url's history list. but if you click back button of browser, '.../history' is disappeared  .[Vue.2]

Comment: This is indeed what I was expecting to happen with the back button, but was not happening. For reasons unknown to me, it is now working as it should.

Comment: LATER: Does not, in fact, appear to be working consistently.

Comment: It's part of a big system, impossible to show here. I'll try to isolate part of it to see if I can demonstrate the issue.

Comment: There is a typo: `relace` -> `replace`